# Convert all datetime fields to UTC

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.3, utc

I've build a web app which is currently being used by a number of customers.
In v1.0 it didn't support time zones and stored all datetimes in Europe/Amsterdam. 
Now in v1.2 it stores all datetimes in UTC and shows the right date in the web app according to the  user's selected time zone.

Now I want to provide a mysql query to my customers (who are updating and already have some data) to update all datetime fields to UTC in phpmyadmin.
I'm using CakePHP so all created/modified fields need to be updated.
Can anyone show me what this query looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the timezone conversion features provided by MySQL itself:

```sql
-- "table" and "field" are obviously placeholders 
UPDATE table SET field = CONVERT_TZ(field, 'Europe/Amsterdam', 'UTC');
```

Be sure to make a backup first.

Note that `CONVERT_TZ` requires MySQL to be aware of the timezones. You can [import them to the database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) with a simple shell command (requires root access to the DB):

```bash
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p -D mysql
```

This can be done multiple times, so it doesn't hurt to execute it if you don't know if the timezones have already been imported. You can usually ignore warnings concerning some obscure timezones.

Comment: Okay this works, thanks!
For events start_date and start_time are stored separate. Can i join these fields, convert them to UTC and store them separately again in one query?

Comment: Yes, that should work. You can basically use the `CONVERT_TZ(field, 'Europe/Amsterdam', 'UTC')` syntax anywhere you can use `field` itself.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me:

UPDATE `events` SET 
`start_date` = CONVERT_TZ(concat(`start_date`,' ',`start_time`), '+02:00', '+00:00'), 
`start_time` = CONVERT_TZ(concat(`start_date`,' ',`start_time`), '+02:00', '+00:00'),
`end_date` = CONVERT_TZ(concat(`end_date`,' ',`end_time`), '+02:00', '+00:00'), 
`end_time` = CONVERT_TZ(concat(`end_date`,' ',`end_time`), '+02:00', '+00:00');

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use the real timezone names (like `Europe/Amsterdam`), because otherwise you get wrong results due to DST.

Comment: Thanks but that's okay for now.. The web app is only 2 weeks old

Comment: If I use real timezone names like 'Europe/Amsterdam' and 'UTC' my fields gets updated to '0000-00-00' and '00:00:00'...

Comment: Did you import the timezones to MySQL?

Comment: No, because i can't expect my customers to have root access to the DB. This query has to work for everyone (e.g. shared hosting, etc.)

Comment: Well duh … if MySQL doesn't know the timezones, it can't convert them. ;) But ok, good to know that it works without importing the timezones when using TZ offsets.